# Streaming large dataset as CSV in Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, csv, java-stream, rest

I have a Spring Boot app (v. 2.3.3) and I need to serve large data sets from the DB (Postgres) via the REST API as CSV-files.
So far, only small subsets of data have been processed, which can be accumulated as collections and transferred at once. Now, I want to make the server ready for large amounts of data.

The data is retrieved as projections (not entities as is) by using queries in a CRUD repository.

```
public interface IMeasurementsRepo extends CrudRepository<Measurement, Long> {
    @Query("SELECT .... ")
    public Iterable<IMeasurementProjection> getMeasurementHistory(...);
}
```

And the projection is defined as the following:

```
public interface IMeasurementProjection {
    public Timestamp getTimestamp();
    public Long getSensorId();
    public Group getGroup();
    public Integer getNum();
    public Signal getSignal();
    public Double getStrength();
}
```

Once retrieved, each projection should be transformed to a line of a CSV-file and sent to a client. Transformation (formatting) is not an issue. My question is how to pass the requested data as a stream.

Most likely, what I need is `ResponseEntity<StreamingResponseBody>` or `Flux`, but I don't know how to apply these in my case.

Any hint or a reference is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using spring-webflux, then along with that r2dbc can achieve what you want, following are the dependency, configuration and working sample

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-r2dbc</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

spring web-flux

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

application.properties

```
spring.r2dbc.url=r2dbc:postgresql://172.17.0.2:5432/streaming-db-server
spring.r2dbc.username=postgres
spring.r2dbc.password=ungabunga
```

Here is the sample code:

```java
package com.example.postgres.batchinsertandstreaming.demo;

import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.data.relational.core.mapping.Table;
import org.springframework.data.repository.reactive.ReactiveCrudRepository;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import reactor.core.publisher.Flux;

import javax.persistence.Id;


@SpringBootApplication
public class PostgresBatchStreamingDataApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(PostgresBatchStreamingDataApplication.class, args);
    }

}

@RequestMapping("streaming")
@RestController
class StreamingSalesRecord {

    private final StreamingSaleRecordService service;

    StreamingSalesRecord(StreamingSaleRecordService service) {
        this.service = service;
    }

    @GetMapping(produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_STREAM_JSON_VALUE)
    public Flux<String> get() {
        return service.all();
    }
}

@Service
class StreamingSaleRecordService {

    private final StreamingSalesRecordRepository repository;

    StreamingSaleRecordService(StreamingSalesRecordRepository repository) {
        this.repository = repository;
    }

    public Flux<String> all() {
        return repository.findAll()
                .map(object -> String.join(",", new String[]{object.getId().toString(), object.getCountry(), object.getRegion()}))
                .map(object -> object + "\n");
    }
}

@Repository
interface StreamingSalesRecordRepository extends ReactiveCrudRepository<SalesRecordReactive, Long> {
}

@Getter
@Setter
@Table(value = "sales_record")
class SalesRecordReactive {

    @Id
    private Long id;

    private String region;

    private String country;
}
```

Comment: CSV files typically have a header column.

Comment: why will streaming data have header, he is talking about either a stream of line with csv values or ndjson

Comment: I interpreted the goal as serving large CSV *files* via API, and CSV files typically have header columns. Streaming was just a way to avoid memory exceptions. If a CSV file without headers is acceptable to consumer, your solution works obviously.

Comment: You can just concat a header like so:
Flux.concat(Flux.just("id,location,colum3header,..."), all());
Where all() returns the CSV Lines without the header (can also be done inside the all() function, obviously)